# выезжающее меню для адаптивного сайта (проблема с уменьшающимся изображением)

Tags: html, jquery, css

Делаю сайт с использованием bootstrap3.

При просмотре с мобильного нужно сделать выезжающее слева меню. Но вопрос не в этом. Меню сделал на jQuery все хорошо работает в настольной версии (где это в последствии не нужно и будет отключено)))) Проблемы возникают на мобильном.

При нажатии кнопки сайт не отодвигается, а уменьшается( Адаптируясь с новому размеру. 
При отключении `meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"` все работает хорошо, но это конечно не выход.

Comment: возможно логичнее и по множеству параметров лучше будет сделать меню  используя bootstrap (у него есть классы специально для навигации ) раз уж вы его используете

Comment: В Bootstrap есть классы для выпадающего меню((( это не совсем отвечает дизайну сайта. Нужно именно выезжающее слева со сдвигом экрана

Answer (score 1):

Главная проблема в теге
    meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
Он масштабирует новый размер содержимого под размер экрана и не дает сдвинуть изображение за его пределы. Проблема решается добавлением в кнопку кода

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content','initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no')
```

Он блокирует масштабирование, плюс запрещает пользователю вручную менять масштаб.